# Adding folders and files using Xcode 4.3.1 and SVN (Subversion)

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control

I just can't get Xcode and SVN to play ball when it comes to committing new files in new folders.  Has anyone worked out the process to do this within the Xcode IDE or do I need to use a third party client?

I don't want to become a Terminal expert and before anyone says use GIT, I want to use SVN because our project management(code review/browsing etc) is integrated with SVN.  SVN also works extremely well with Microsoft and Android development.

**Background:**  I like to separate my files into various folders (Data, Model, View etc).  Currently I create the new folder in Finder, then add the folder in Xcode and start creating files and cutting code.  When it comes to committing, all hell breaks loose.  I'll go into Organizer and import the folder.  At this point things look good but it goes pear-shaped after that.  I've tried many things, sometimes getting an "A" symbol but at the end of the day, the integration just isn't there.

Thanks

Comment: I just bought Cornerstone and use Xcode for diff, been happy ever since ^^

Comment: When you "_create the new folder in Finder, then add the folder in Xcode and start creating files_", do you add the folder into Subversion first? By the way, I use [Pathfinder](http://cocoatech.com/) as a Finder replacement. It has a built in Subversion client. I highly recommend anyone who is a Power Mac user to get Pathfinder.

Comment: Hi David. No I tend not to think about version control until after I have completed and tested the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this if it is help full to you

Issue similar to yours:

Close Xcode + Organiser
Open your svn web address in Safari (not any other browser) - using the dns name
It should come up saying the address is untrusted as the cert is a different name / address
Click show certificate and then tick the box saying always trust then continue
it may prompt you for your mac username / password to add to the keychain
Open xcode and try again using the DNS name..
The issue with xcode and accessing svn servers which have HTTPS certificates which fail any of the checks (be it host matching, self signed etc..). Opening the addresses in safari and adding as trusted solves this problem!

Thanks!!

Comment: I think may well help but still couldn't get it to work.  Ended up giving up and buying Cornerstone, thanks to @fbernardo's suggestion